# Socket.io : Emitting to specific user not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I'm trying to send a message to a particular socket.io client.

I've stored his socket ID in redis, and retrieve it.

```
redisClient.get(req.user._id, function (err, key) {
    console.log(key);
    console.log(global.io.sockets.connected[key]);

    // I seem to be getting the socket properly, but emitting doesn't work:
    global.io.sockets.connected[key].emit('test');     
});
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Needs a little more detail. Do you get an error or exception, or does no error occur yet the client not receive the message?

Comment: No error occurs, but the client doesn't receive the message.

Comment: Can you post some more details about how you've set up socket.io?